# Simple img link issue

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

This may sound stupid, however I cannot figure out why this a href link on the below img tag isn't working:

HTML:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>

<div class="logo">
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
</div>

  <ul>
     <li class='active'><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
     <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Products</a>
        <ul>
           <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle for the above: http://jsfiddle.net/q7cH9/

For some reason the code is W3C valid and no errors are being given.

Comment: what do you means exactly by : 'href link isn't working'?

Comment: This is a fiddle to see what is happening: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7CB2/

Comment: That fiddle isn't going to work because fiddle does not contain a images/logo.png file?

Comment: no it's ok thanks to the alt tag in the image

Comment: Have you checked the file exists and is accessible and is images/logo.png is the correct path to the file relative to your html doc? This is really very, very basic stuff.

Comment: Well, the problem comes from the propriety float:left; in the class .logo. But honestly, i don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: @Liam I know this is very basic stuff and I am amazed myself why this is happening... Here I updated the fiddle with a live logo : http://jsfiddle.net/q7cH9/

Comment: No it works fine, I'm testing the code on my browser.

Comment: @Sushant I have no idea what are you seeing working I am testing on Chrome, Firefox & IE and none of them works

Comment: @Liam - My question above states that the a href link on the image tag isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved by adding the below css to the image link:

```
position:relative;
z-index:10000;
```

Comment: Thus locking your site into an ever increasing z-index based arms struggle

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the `float:left;` on the `.logo` div, which is resulting in the div collapsing (which means your div becomes with 0 height).
The solution is to clear the float after that div, add this to your code after the logo div

`<br style="clear:both;" />`

And here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/q7cH9/1/)**.

And here is a reference to [**div collapsing**](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: The problem with the above is that the menu is now styling underneath the logo which I don't want that, I want the logo on the left hand side and the menu on the right hand side in one line

Answer (score 1):

```
 #cssmenu a {
    background: #333;
    color: #CBCBCB;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000; 
}
```

Please replace this class in style css.

Comment: This worked for me.  The problem is the ul from your menu is the full width of the screen and sitting on top of your logo.

Answer (score -1):

Edit : is this what you are looking for ?

http://jsfiddle.net/f5Q3Y/

I did some changes to the `css`

Comment: This is breaking the theme layout! - Logo is coming on top whereas the menu is underneath, I want everything side by side

Comment: what is the resolution of the image? (as we don't have that one available).

Comment: The image resolution is 200x66